# Multi Patterns on one Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I want to draw multiple patterns on one canvas. I could load several images using a callback function, but when I try to draw the patterns, nothing happends. It is suposed that a pattern of a wall, and a patter of a roof appear on the same canvas. But the opening of the html in my browser (mozilla), only opens a blank page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> EXAMPLE </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $.getJSON("example01.json", function(data) {

      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.width = data.map.width;
      canvas.height = data.map.height;

      var count = 0;
      for (property in data.map) {
        count++;
      }

      var sources = new Array(count - 2);
      var wallExist = data.map.wall.brick;
      var roofExist = data.map.roof.tile;

      if (typeof (wallExist) != "undefined") {
        switch (data.map.wall.brick) {
          case "01":
            sources[0] = "./brick01.png";
            break;

          case "02":
            sources[0] = "./brick02.png";
            break;
        }
      }


      if (typeof (roofExist) != "undefined") {
        switch (roofExist) {
          case "01" :
            sources[1] = "./roof01.png";

          case "02" :
            sources[1] = "./roof02.png";
        }

        function loadImages(sources, callback) {
          var images = new Array();
          var loadedImages = 0;
          var numImages = 0;
          var patterns = new Array();

          for (var src in sources) {
            numImages++;
          }

          for (i = 0; i <= sources.length; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image();
            images[i].onload = function() {
              if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                callback(images);
              }
            };
            images[i].src = sources[i];
            patterns[i] = ctx.createPattern(image[i], "repeat");
          }
        }

        loadImages(sources, function(images) {
          ctx.rect(data.map.wall.x_pos, data.map.wall.y_pos, data.map.wall.width, data.map.wall.height);
          ctx.fill(pattern[0]);
          ctx.rect(data.map.roof.x_pos, data.map.roof.y_pos, data.map.roof.width, dat.map.roof.height);
          ctx.fill(pattern[1]);
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Well, you're already doing `ctx.createPattern` on images *that do not yet have loaded*. Put that in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're doing `patterns[i] = ctx.createPattern(image[i], "repeat");` when the respective image does not yet have loaded.

Also, in the `loadImages` callback you're accessing a `pattern` array that doesn't exist (and `patterns` is out of scope). And `fill()` doesn't take the pattern as a parameter, but you need to set the `.fillStyle` property of the context before.

Last but not least you've put the `loadImages` function declaration and its call inside the `if (roofExist)` clause, it should come after it.

For fun, I've also rewritten your logic not to use all those arrays or objects, as they seem a little unnecessary given that your filling them in only conditionally.

```
function draw(ctx, item, prop, imgname) {
  if (!item || !item[prop]) return; // abort, doesn't exist

  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(image, "repeat");
    ctx.rect(item.x_pos, item.y_pos, item.width, item.height);
    ctx.fill();
  };
  image.src = imgname+item[prop]+".png";
}
$.getJSON("example01.json", function(data) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = data.map.width;
  canvas.height = data.map.height;

  draw(ctx, data.map.wall, "brick", "./brick");
  draw(cty, data.map.roof, "tile", "./roof");
});
```